# Google Sheets with Calendar Integration + Times based on conditions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm running into an issue while trying to run the following code to set events based on Google Sheets to Calendar, pretty much what I'm trying to achieve is :

If the user enters ***High***: The calendar should look for the next available time slot and set the event there

If the user enters ***Mid***: Look for the first third of time between the next upcoming event and the one already established, ie: One event at 9 am already and another at 12 Pm, so if I'm trying to set a new event under the priority Mid, it should set it at 10 am

If the user enters ***Low***: Look for the second third of timebetween the next upcoming event and the one already established, ie: One event at 9 am already and another at 12 Pm, so if I'm trying to set a new event under the priority Mid, it should set it at 11 am

If there are no available ***Time Slots in Between*** give an alert.

So far the script is setting up the time under any entry for the next upcoming event

Also, I'm stuck at setting the events to be between 6 AM and 11 PM for the default calendar.

Big piece of code here, so any insights would be truly appreciated it

```
//schedule event
function schedEvent() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Scheduler');
  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();

  if(lrow<2)
    return;

  var edata = ss.getRange(lrow, 1, 1, 9).getValues()[0];

  if(edata[5]=='Scheduled')
    return;

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
//  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('ecmoranavila@gmail.com');

  var d = new Date();
  var dl = new Date(edata[2].getTime() + 1000*3600*24);
  var events = calendar.getEvents(d, dl);
  var eId = '';

  Logger.log(d);

  var to_dl = (dl-d);
  var et = edata[3];
  var st;
  var d1;
  var d2 = dl;

  if(edata[4]=='High') {
    d1 = new Date(Math.max(d, new Date(new Date().setHours(23,0,0,0))))
    d2 = new Date(Math.min(d2, new Date(new Date().setHours(6,0,0,0))))
    if(events.length==0) {
      st = d1;
    } else {
      st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
    }

  } else if(edata[4]=='Mid') {

    //check 2nd third
    d1 = new Date(Math.max(new Date(d.getTime() + to_dl/0.33), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl).setHours(6,0,0,0))));
    d2 = new Date(Math.min(new Date(d.getTime() + to_dl/0.33), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl).setHours(11,0,0,0))));
    if(events.length==0) {
      st = d1;
    } else {
      st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
    }

    //check 1st third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
      d1 = new Date(Math.max(d, new Date(new Date().setHours(23,0,0,0))))
      d2 = new Date(Math.min(new Date(d.getTime() + to_dl/0.33), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl).setHours(11,0,0,0))));
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

    //check 3rd third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
      d1 = new Date(Math.max(new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3/to_dl), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl).setHours(23,0,0,0))));
      d2 = new Date(Math.min(dl, new Date(new Date(dl).setHours(6,0,0,0))));
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

  } else if(edata[4]=='Low') {

    //check 3rd third
    d1 = new Date(Math.max(new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl).setHours(23,0,0,0))));
    d2 = new Date(Math.min(dl, new Date(new Date(dl).setHours(6,0,0,0))));
    if(events.length==0) {
      st = d1;
    } else {
      st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
    }

    //check 2nd third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
    d1 = new Date(Math.max(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl).setHours(23,0,0,0))));
    d2 = new Date(Math.min(new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl).setHours(6,0,0,0))));
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

    //check 1st third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
      d1 = new Date(Math.max(d, new Date(new Date().setHours(23,0,0,0))))
      d2 = new Date(Math.min(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl).setHours(6,0,0,0))));
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

  }

  Logger.log(st);
  if(st=='No available time slots') {
    edata[5] = st;
    edata[6] = '';
    edata[7] = '';
    ss.getRange(lrow, 1, 1, 9).setValues([edata]);  
  } else {
    st = new Date(st);
    edata[5] = 'Scheduled';
    edata[6] = st
    edata[7] = Utilities.formatDate(st, 'CST', 'hh:mm:ss a');
    edata[8] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(st.getTime() + et*3600000), 'CST', 'hh:mm:ss a');
    Logger.log(st);
    Logger.log(new Date(st.getTime() + et*3600000));

    var event = calendar.createEvent(edata[1], new Date(st), new Date(st.getTime() + et*3600000));
    eId = event.getId();
    ss.getRange(lrow, 1, 1, 9).setValues([edata]);        
  }  

}

//find other time for the event
function reschEvent(ss_prty, calendar, edata) {
  var d = new Date();
  edata[7] = new Date(edata[7]);
  edata[8] = new Date(edata[8]);
  var events = calendar.getEvents(d, edata[7]);
  var eId = '';

  Logger.log(d);

  var to_dl = (edata[7]-d);
  var et = (edata[8]-edata[7])/3600000;
  var st;
  var d1;
  var d2 = edata[7];

  if(edata[5]=='High') {

    if(events.length==0) {
      st = d;
    } else {
      st = checkInterval(et, events, d, d2);
    }

  } else if(edata[5]=='Mid') {

    //check 2nd third
    d1 = new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl);
    d2 = new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl);
    if(events.length==0) {
      st = d1;
    } else {
      st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
    }

    //check 1st third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
      d1 = d;
      d2 = new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl);
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

    //check 3rd third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
      d1 = new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl);
      d2 = edata[7];
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

  } else if(edata[5]=='Low') {

    //check 3rd third
    d1 = new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl);
    d2 = edata[7];
    if(events.length==0) {
      st = d1;
    } else {
      st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
    }

    //check 2nd third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
      d1 = new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl);
      d2 = new Date(d.getTime() + 2/3*to_dl);
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

    //check 1st third
    if(st=='No available time slots') {
      d1 = d;
      d2 = new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl);
      if(events.length==0) {
        st = d1;
      } else {
        st = checkInterval(et, events, d1, d2);
      }
    }

  }

  if(st=='No available time slots') {
    edata[6] = st;
    edata[7] = '';
    edata[8] = '';
    edata[9] = '';
    ss_prty.getRange(ss_prty.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues([edata]);  
  } else {
    edata[6] = 'Rescheduled';
    edata[7] = st.getDate();
    edata[8] = Utilities.formatDate(st, 'CST', 'hh:mm:ss a');
    edata[9] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(st.getTime() + et*3600000), 'CST', 'hh:mm:ss a');
    Logger.log(st);
    Logger.log(new Date(st.getTime() + et*3600000));
    var event = calendar.createEvent(edata[1], st, new Date(st.getTime() + et*3600000));
    eId = event.getId();
    ss_prty.getRange(ss_prty.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues([edata]);        
  }  

  return eId;

}

function checkInterval(et, events, d, dl) {
  var dt;
  var st;

  Logger.log(events.length);
  for(var i=0; i<=events.length; i++) {

    if(i==0) {
      dt = (events[i].getStartTime()-d)/3600000;
    } else if (i==events.length) {
      dt = (dl-events[i-1].getEndTime())/3600000;
    } else {
      dt = (events[i].getStartTime() - events[i-1].getEndTime())/3600000;
    }
    Logger.log(dt);

    if(dt>et) {
      if(i==0) {
        Logger.log(d);
        st = d;
      } else {
        Logger.log(events[i-1].getEndTime());
        st = events[i-1].getEndTime();
      }
      return st;
    }
  }
  if(!st)
    return 'No available time slots';
}
```

Comment: Hello @ErickssonMoran, so what exactly is your **question**? Cheers!

Comment: Pretty much how to set the priorities as described, I'm not able to get the times to be scheduled as per the priorities entered by the user

Comment: Hello @ErickssonMoran, would you mind sharing a sanitized copy of your sheet as well? That would be of great help :) Cheers!

Comment: I resolved it by changing  '''   d1 = new Date(Math.max(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() +to_dl*0.33).setHours(23,0,0,0))));
    d2 = new Date(Math.min(new Date(d.getTime() +to_dl*0.33), new Date(new Date(d.getTime()

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by changing

`d1 = new Date(Math.max(new Date(d.getTime() + 1/3*to_dl), new Date(new Date(d.getTime() +to_dl*0.33).setHours(23,0,0,0)))); d2 = new Date(Math.min(new Date(d.getTime() +to_dl*0.33), new Date(new Date(d.getTime()`